# $\sum_{r=0}^m{^n}C_rk^ r$ m<n

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is it? I've tried a few futile things with adding powers of $x$ to try and change the factorials to powers, but I think that approach remains futile.
If no nice formula what's the best way to bound it if we're in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Binomial expand $(1+k)^n$

Comment: have you tried small values of $n$ and $k$? there is a very known pattern there.

Comment: Sorry first version misstated.